# how to count the total number of comment

Tags: php, mysql

i want to count the total comment/post posted on my page. i have a table in my database named test. within table i have a column named comment, where every post is been stored. the problem am having is to echo out the total number of comment and keep updating as viewers keep on posting there comment and i tried using this code:

```
$handle = mysql_query("SELECT `comment`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
     FROM test GROUP BY `comment` ");
if ($handle) {
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle);
    echo ($results[0]['count'] + $results[1]['count']);
}
```

but it keeps on echoing out 0.

Comment: "A *déjà vu* is a glitch in the Matrix... it happens when they change something..."

Comment: `count` is a reserved word. Use another name like C, and just `$results['C']` (no `$results[0]..`

Comment: @davidkonrad That's what the backticks are for. You can name a column anything you like, especially an alias.

Comment: but the $results{0] is wrong anyway. Why bother using count and backticks?

Comment: Group by will return count for similar comments which is very unlikely to happen, so first thing take out group by and then check if $results[0]['count'] is correct and finally check here how counts can be gathered with query http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/558d5/1

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns a SINGLE row of results from the query, so

```
echo ($results[0]['count'] + $results[1]['count']);
```

is incorrect. You're treating `$results` as a multidimensional array that holds ALL of your result rows. You'd need this:

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle); // fetch 1st row
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle); // fetch 2nd row

$total = $row1['count'] + $row2['count'];
```

A `var_dump($results)` would easily confirm this, if you'd bothered looking.

Comment: tanx allot am grateful @ Marc B, i tried using d sample u posted it works. but it echo out 2 and that is not the total post. what i needed is i want it to display like it is in this page, that it will echo out 1 answer or 2 answer as people keep on answering it keep on updating  something like that pls. thank you